# Python and Scrapy issue with attrib

Tags: python, scrapy

Good day everyone and Happy new Year :D

I am new to scrapy and wanted to use attrib method in order to understand it fully. I used [this site](https://quotes.toscrape.com/)
for scraping. When I run `response.css(".quote span").attrib["itemprop"]` it gives and error like **SelectorList object has no attribute "attrib"** even though there is such kind of method. How to write it in order to make it work and why it is not working in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this css selector

```
[x.attrib['itemprop'] for x in response.css('span.text')]
```

or using xpath

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]/span/@itemprop').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks, i just wanted to know why mine is not working. Do i have an old version of scrapy maybe

Comment: response.css(".quote span").attrib["itemprop"] , its ok in my scrapy shell terminal. could you please put full error.

Comment: my scrapy was outdated =( It worked after pip upgared